# Working Around Concurrency Limits in AWS Glue

Tags: python, boto3, aws-glue

I have a question around how best to manage concurrent job instances in AWS glue.

I have a job defined like so:

```
job = client.create_job(
        Name='JOB_NAME', 
        Role='the-role-name',
        ExecutionProperty={
            'MaxConcurrentRuns': 25
        },
        Command={'Name': 'glueetl',
                 'ScriptLocation': script_location,
                 'PythonVersion': '3'},
        Tags={'Application': 'app',
              'Project': 'proj'},
        GlueVersion='2.0',
        WorkerType='G.2X',
        NumberOfWorkers=50
    )
```

I want to call about 1000 instances of this job like so:

```
def run_job(f):
    response = client.start_job_run(
                JobName = JOB_NAME,
                Arguments = {
                    '--start_date':  start_date,
                    '--end_date':  end_date,
                    '--factor':  f} )
    return response


for f in factors:
        response = run_job(f)
        print(f"response: {response}")
```

The issue with this approach is #1 firing off all these requests at once will throw a throttling error and #2 if I sleep between job starts I still run up against concurrency limit which is 50.

Does anyone know an easy way to work around these issues?

Comment: You defined your job with `ExecutionProperty={'MaxConcurrentRuns': 25}` , what do you expect?

Comment: I suppose my real question is, do glue jobs queue automatically?

Comment: No they do not. If you exceed your max concurrent limit, an exception will be thrown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Max concurrent job runs per account" limit is a soft limit (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/glue.html). Maybe log a service request with AWS and ask for an increase in the limit. The second thing is I am not sure how you have implemented your sleep action in the code, maybe instead of doing just a sleep catch the exception each time you make the call, if there is an exception, sleep with an exponential backoff in seconds and try again when sleep time is finished and repeat until your get a positive response OR when you reach your own set limit to stop. This way your processing will not stop until you give up, but just slow down when throtteling kicks in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the on_failure operator in Airflow to catch the specific error that you are looking for. The on_failure operator allows you to specify a function that will be called when a task fails. In your case, you could use the on_failure operator to call a function that will retry the task after a delay, or to monitor the resources available for the Glue job and kick it off when one of the 25 running jobs finishes.

Here is an example of how to use the on_failure operator to retry a task after a delay:

Python

'''

```
def retry_task(context):
    delay = 60 * 5  # 5 minutes

    print("Task failed, retrying in {} seconds".format(delay))
    time.sleep(delay)

    task_id = context["task_id"]
    dag = context["dag"]

    dag.retry(task_id)


dag = DAG("my_dag", start_date=datetime.today())

task = PythonOperator(
    task_id="my_task",
    python_callable=retry_task,
    on_failure=retry_task,
)

dag.add_task(task)
```

'''

This code will retry the task my_task if it fails. The task will be retried after a delay of 5 minutes.

You can also use the on_failure operator to monitor the resources available for the Glue job and kick it off when one of the 25 running jobs finishes. Here is an example:

Python

'''

```
def monitor_resources(context):

    job_name = context["task_id"].split(".")[0]
    glue_job = GlueJob(job_name=job_name)

    while True:
        if glue_job.get_running_count() < 25:
        print("There are less than 25 running jobs, kicking off the task")
        break

    time.sleep(10)


dag = DAG("my_dag", start_date=datetime.today())

task = PythonOperator(
    task_id="my_task",
    python_callable=monitor_resources,
    on_failure=monitor_resources,
)

dag.add_task(task)
```

'''

This code will monitor the resources available for the Glue job my_task. If there are less than 25 running jobs, the task will be kicked off.